# Return Open Files in Process in Go on Windows

Tags: windows, process, go, handle

What is the best way to get the number of files open by a process in Go on Windows? I'm trying to avoid using a wrapper around [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) since it cannot be redistributed. On Linux/Mac, one could use the `os/exec` package to call the `lsof` command, but there doesn't seem to be a native `lsof` equivalent in Windows.

Comment: Simple high utility Bash command; nightmare to execute on Windows. Cygwin ftw?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal lol, hmmm...not sure if Cygwin is an option...I may have to rethink my approach if it is too complex to implement

Comment: How about something like this from a cgo test: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/misc/cgo/test/issue8517_windows.go#L18-L31? Is there a way I could combine this with `os.Getpid()` to get the handle count for the currently executing Go program?